# Possible to read in csv data to SQL Server / SSMS with only read access

Tags: sql-server, csv, import, ssms

I'm new to SQL Server so am probably missing a core concept here. I'm trying to do a LEFT JOIN on a `.CSV` doc that contains about 2,000 records, merging from a SQL Server database table that has millions of records. I only have read access, so (I think) I can't create tables or databases. In Python or R, I would read-in the data as a variable, but all the things I've seen about working with `.CSV` data with SQL Server instructs me to add it as a table in the database.

Is there a workaround here since I don't have permission? It's not really a table I'd want in the database anyway.  And I would like to avoid first exporting the table with millions of records if possible. I am using SSMS 18.2 if that matters.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to import the CSV into a #temptable and then join to your temp table. The temp table will go away after you close your connection. The question is how to create and populate the temp table, and whether you can get the rights to do so.

What permissions do you have? If you have Bulk Insert (via the BulkAdmin server role), you can create a temp table and import your CSV into it, even if you only have db_datareader on the database. Good example: https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/02/06/sql-server-import-csv-file-into-sql-server-using-bulk-insert-load-comma-delimited-file-into-sql-server/

```
/* Save this to C:\temp\testfile.csv:
1,James,Smith,19750101
2,Meggie,Smith,19790122
3,Robert,Smith,20071101
4,Alex,Smith,20040202
*/
CREATE TABLE #CSVTest
(
ID INT,
FirstName VARCHAR(40),
LastName VARCHAR(40),
BirthDate smalldatetime
)

BULK INSERT #CSVTest
FROM 'c:\temp\testfile.csv'
WITH
(
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
GO
```

You can also read CSV and other files by using OpenRowset, some version of this:

```
select *
from openrowset('MSDASQL'
,'Driver={Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv)}'
,'select * from C:\Test.CSV')
```

but there are often security issues here as well.

You could also try using Access: import the CSV to a table, then link in the SQL table. But I don't know that a million row join is going to work very well, and you might get a call from your DBA if it slows things down too much.

The easiest thing would be to see if they'll grant you the BulkAdmin role.

Comment: Thanks, Will.  I can create the temp table, but am denied access from using Bulk Insert to populate it, so I guess I have a lower level of access than db_datareader.  I haven't tried the second solution you provide, but I ended up exporting the columns I needed from the the big database (>5M) and joining it to my data in R.  I'm going to pursue db_datareader permissions, so thanks for helping me figure that out.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this SQL query:

```
with csvtable(col1, col2, col3, col4) as
(
select col1, col2, col3, col4 -- first csv file record
union all
select col1, col2, col3, col4 -- second csv file record
union all
.....
select col1, col2, col3, col4 -- two thousandth csv file record
)
select t1.col1, t1.col2, t2.col1, t2.col2
from csvtable t1
left join table2M t2 on ...
```